# Resizing row height of list widget

Tags: python, qt

So I'm using pyqt and I'm trying to populate my List with items that contain an icon and some text beside it.  My icons gets shrunk down when inserted to the List and my font size is super small.  How do I increase size of everything  (i.e size of icon and text)?

Answer (score 0):

The icon size and the font can be set on the view widget with `setIconSize` and `setFont`.

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  I was originally using setSizeHint which only made the rows taller without making the icon or text bigger.